Rust minesweeper grid generator code design
I wrote this not really to create a minesweeper game, but to practice using some of the "rusty" (but not only) design patterns and improving my code structure.
I would appreciate a review of the code:
#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug, Clone)]
pub enum MinesweeperError {
    #[error("Too many bombs")]
    TooManyBombs,
    #[error("Bombs cannot be placed outside of the grid")]
    BombsOutsideBounds,
    #[error("Grid dimensions cannot be 0")]
    InvalidDimensions,
}



#[derive(Debug, Clone, Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Coord {
    i: usize,
    j: usize
}

impl Coord {
    pub fn new(i: usize, j: usize) -> Self {
        Self { i, j }
    }

    /// returns an iterator over the neighbors of a coord
    pub fn neighbors(&self, rows: usize, cols: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = Self> + '_ {
        let lower_i = self.i.saturating_sub(1);
        let lower_j = self.j.saturating_sub(1);
        let upper_i = (rows - 1).min(self.i + 1);
        let upper_j = (cols - 1).min(self.j + 1);

        debug!("center: {:?}, bounds: {:?} - {:?}", self, (lower_i, lower_j), (upper_i, upper_j));

        (lower_i..=upper_i)
        .flat_map(move |r| (lower_j..=upper_j).map(move |c| Self::new(r, c)))
        .filter(move |coord| coord != self)
    }
}



#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct NonZeroDimensions {
    rows: usize,
    cols: usize
}

impl NonZeroDimensions {
    pub fn parse(rows: usize, cols: usize) -> Result<Self, MinesweeperError> {
        if rows == 0 || cols == 0 {
            return Err(MinesweeperError::InvalidDimensions);
        }

        Ok(Self { rows, cols })
    }
}



#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct DimensionsWithBombsAmount {
    dims: NonZeroDimensions,
    amount: usize
}

impl DimensionsWithBombsAmount {
    pub fn parse(dims: NonZeroDimensions, amount: usize) -> Result<Self, MinesweeperError> {
        if amount > dims.rows * dims.cols {
            return Err(MinesweeperError::TooManyBombs);
        }

        Ok(Self { dims, amount })
    }

    /// provides random coords given size of the grid and amount
    pub fn n_random_coords(&self) -> HashSet<Coord> {
        // probably not very efficient/fast but that doesn't matter here
        let mut all_coords = (0..self.dims.rows)
            .flat_map(|i| (0..self.dims.cols).map(move |j| Coord::new(i, j)))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    
        random_shuffle(&mut all_coords);
    
        // won't ever panic beacuse first it has to be verified by ::parse()
        all_coords[0..self.amount].iter().cloned().collect()
    }
    
}

pub fn random_shuffle<T>(list: &mut [T]) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    list.shuffle(&mut rng);
}



#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct DimensionsWithBombs {
    dims: NonZeroDimensions,
    bombs: HashSet<Coord>
}

impl DimensionsWithBombs {
    pub fn parse(dims: NonZeroDimensions, bombs: HashSet<Coord>) -> Result<Self, MinesweeperError> {
        DimensionsWithBombsAmount::parse(dims, bombs.len())?;

        if bombs.iter().any(|bomb_coord| bomb_coord.i >= dims.rows || bomb_coord.j >= dims.cols) {
            return Err(MinesweeperError::BombsOutsideBounds);
        }

        Ok(Self { dims, bombs })
    }

    pub fn new_with_random_bombs(dims_with_amounts: DimensionsWithBombsAmount) -> Self {
        let bombs = dims_with_amounts.n_random_coords();

        let DimensionsWithBombsAmount {
            dims,
            ..
        } = dims_with_amounts;
        
        Self { dims, bombs }
    }

    pub fn new_with_no_bombs(dims: NonZeroDimensions) -> Self {
        Self { dims, bombs: HashSet::new() }
    }
}



#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum MinesweeperCell {
    Num(i32),
    Bomb
}

impl MinesweeperCell {
    pub fn increment_if_possible(&mut self) {
        if let Self::Num(n) = self {
           *n += 1;
        }
    }
}



#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Minesweeper {
    pub cells: Vec<Vec<MinesweeperCell>>
}

impl Minesweeper {
    pub fn new_with_bombs(dims_with_bombs: DimensionsWithBombs) -> Self {
        let rows = dims_with_bombs.dims.rows;
        let cols = dims_with_bombs.dims.cols;
        let bombs = dims_with_bombs.bombs;

        let mut cells = vec![vec![MinesweeperCell::Num(0); cols]; rows];

        bombs.iter()
            .for_each(|b| cells[b.i][b.j] = MinesweeperCell::Bomb);

        debug!("bomb cells: {:?}", cells);

        bombs.iter()
            .flat_map(|b| b.neighbors(rows, cols))
            .for_each(|b| {
                let cell = &mut cells[b.i][b.j];
                cell.increment_if_possible();
            });

        debug!("bomb and num cells: {:?}", cells);

        Self { cells }
    }

    pub fn new_random(dims_with_amounts: DimensionsWithBombsAmount) -> Self {
        let dims_with_bombs = DimensionsWithBombs::new_with_random_bombs(dims_with_amounts);

        Self::new_with_bombs(dims_with_bombs)
    }

    pub fn new_empty(dims: NonZeroDimensions) -> Self {
        let dims_with_bombs = DimensionsWithBombs::new_with_no_bombs(dims);

        Self::new_with_bombs(dims_with_bombs)
    }

    // not important
    pub fn show(&self) {
        for row in &self.cells {
            let row_string: Vec<String> = row.iter().map(|cell| {
                match cell {
                    MinesweeperCell::Num(n) => format!("{} ", n),
                    MinesweeperCell::Bomb => format!("B "),
                }
            }).collect();
            println!("{}", row_string.join(" "));
        }
    }
}

Example usage:
let dims = NonZeroDimensions::parse(2, 5)?;

let example_empty = Minesweeper::new_empty(dims);
example_empty.show();
// 0  0  0  0  0
// 0  0  0  0  0

let bombs_amount = 4;
let example_random = Minesweeper::new_random(DimensionsWithBombsAmount::parse(dims, bombs_amount)?);
example_random.show();
// possible outcome: 
// 0  1  B  B  3 
// 0  1  3  B  B

let bombs = HashSet::from([Coord::new(1, 1), Coord::new(0, 3)]);
let example_rigged = Minesweeper::new_with_bombs(DimensionsWithBombs::parse(dims, bombs)?);
example_rigged.show();
// 1  1  2  B  1
// 1  B  2  1  1

I personally think it's well-structured, but I'm uncertain if this is the right overall pattern for big projects. For one, I noticed that using this code might not be as straight-forward for users of this minesweeper library. One might think of writing:
Minesweeper::new_random(5, 5, 10)?;

instead of:
Minesweeper::new_random(DimensionsWithBombAmounts::parse(NonZeroDimensions::parse(5, 5)?, 10)?);

It's a trade-off between being simple to use (first) and loosely coupled and easier to test (second). How do I deal with such dilemmas?
Besides that are some parts redundant or misplaced? Any anti-patterns?

I currently don't have the time for a full review. I'd not use a nested vec, but a structure that stores one of the dimensions' value.
